# How to bundle local gem dependancies in IronWorker

Tags: ruby, ironworker, iron.io

I have a Ruby IronWorker which depends on a private gem that isn't published to RubyGems.

Is there a way to merge this local `mygemname-0.0.1.gem` into my IronWorker in the `.worker` file?

I'm hoping to be able to specify something the following in myruby.worker:

```
gem 'mygemname', '>=0.0.1', :path=> 'vendor/bundle'
```

Currently this give the following error

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/iron_worker_ng-0.12.2/lib/iron_worker_ng/code/base.rb:79 :in `eval':
   wrong number of arguments (3 for 2) (ArgumentError)
```

Hoping for defaults gives:

```
 gem 'mygemname', '>=0.0.1'
```

Gives the following error

```
Could not find gem 'mygemname (>= 0.0.1) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

Am I on the right track trying to get this to work via the .worker file?  Or should I be looking into specifying a custom build step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, git and local paths unsupported right now.
Here is way to manually include local gem:
Add these lines to .worker file:

```
dir '../vendor/bundle/mygemname', '__gems__/gems'
file '../vendor/bundle/mygemname/mygemname.gemspec', '__gems__/specifications'
```

Comment: I've added some details below showing how to handle the case where your unpublished gem has dependancies

Answer (score 3):

If your unpublished gem itself has dependancies, you need to do a little massaging to get things going.  Here is a technique that works for me:

`mygem.worker`

```
runtime "ruby"

#Merge in an unpublished local gem
dir '../opensource-cli-tools/facebook_exporter', '__gems__/gems'
file '../opensource-cli-tools/facebook_exporter/mygem.gemspec', '__gems__/specifications'

#Merge in a custom build script to fetch the unpublished gem's dependancies
file "Gemfile"
file "install_dependancies.sh"

remote_build_command 'chmod +x install_dependancies.sh && ./install_dependancies.sh'

#Run the puppy!
exec "run.rb"
```

`install_dependancies.sh`

```
echo "Installing dependancies to __gems__/"
gem install bundler --install-dir ./__gems__ --no-ri --no-rdoc
bundle install --standalone --path ./__gems__
cp -R ./__gems__/ruby/*/* ./__gems__
rm -rf ./__gems__/ruby
echo "Fixing install location of mygem"
mv ./__gems__/gems/mygem ./__gems__/gems/mygem-0.0.1
```